# User edit form same as registration form

Tags: forms, users

The title says it all: I want the page at */user/ID/edit* to look exactly the same as */user/register* form. Of course, the submit-button-action would have to be a little bit different, but the form elements shall stay the same and inherit their default values from $user.

Does anyone have some sort of snippets that do this job? Or are there any best practices around without using additional modules e.g. panels, profile2, etc.?!

Comment: Since no one has replied.. Why? What changes in particular are you looking for?